# slow update query with redshift from python 3 using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I'm using this code to update several records on Redshift (around 30.000 records per run).

```
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
sql_string_update = """UPDATE my_table SET "outlier_reason" = {0} WHERE "id" = {1};"""
for id, row in df_ignored.iterrows():
    sql_ = sql_string_update.format(row['outlier_reason'],id)
    cur.execute(sql_)
conn.commit()
```

Every run of around 30.000 elements takes up to 2 hours of execution.

Is there a way to speed up this query?

Comment: You are running 30.000 updates on the database, there is no way this can get any faster. My recommendation is create a logic to 1. create a file in S3 for `insert`  the new rows 2. `delete` the rows need to be updated. 3. use `copy` to load data from S3 to Redshift. Let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 1):

In think instead of touching the table and doing updates one by one, you should be using ETL way of doing things, I believe that would be much faster. Should take care of 30K records in few minutes. Here is approach.

1. Create a staging table, say `stg_my_table (id,outlier_reason)`.
2. Write your Python programs data into a CSV file or JSON file, whatever suits your case. Save it to `S3` or `EC2`.
3. Use `copy` [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-s3.html#copy-parameters-data-source-s3-examples) to load into stg_my_table along with ID.
4. Do an Update to `my_table` by joining it with `stg_my_table` using the ID and set `outlier_reason`.

I think above solution must reduce time of processing from 2 Hrs to few minutes.
Please try this way may be manually before writing the actual code. I'm sure you will see very promising results and then optimize each of above steps one by one to even gain more performance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That sounds like a lot of work. I'll give it a try, pity there is no simpler solution.

Comment: @otmezger Redshift is not designed for very frequent updates and surely its not for individual single records updates as its columnar database.